# How can I run shell commands on another server from Jenkins service?

Tags: javascript, shell, jenkins

I have a node project with pm2  I want to create a shell script on Jenkins to triger the build
I have watched a lot of tutorials but i cant seem to find any good way to fix the problem.

Here is what I have tried

```
ssh   -tt -i privKey username@ip/backend 
npm install
node server.js
```

Here what I need to do

```
1.Connect to the server
2.Run npm install
3.Reload pm2.json
```

But the shell script is failing to connect to the server and to run the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt -i privKey username@ip  <<EOF       
     cd backend
     npm install
     node server.js
     pm2 reload pm2.json
     echo 'Process completed successfully.'
     exit      
    EOF
```

1. Sometimes when connecting through ssh tunnel, changing directory can
   cause premission access problems, so first connect to server than
   change directory.
2. **StrictHostKeyChecking=no**: The option StrictHostKeyChecking specifies whether or not ssh will automatically add new host keys to the $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts file, or never automatically add new host keys to the host file. This option, when set to yes, provides maximum protection against Trojan horse attacks.
3. **<<EOF** - End of line, used for multi-line shell command.
4. **cd backend** - changes directory to backend after connectiong to server.
5. **echo:** Prints a string to know when this process is finnished.
6. **exit:** to exit out of server's shell